# No updating collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I use 0.6.4.  Don't work `Collection.update(t.data._id, { $set: { name: e.currentTarget.value}}); Session.set("edit-" + t.data._id, false);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using jQuery to extract the value: `$(e.currentTarget).val()`. Also, assuming the `person` template is rendered from an `{{#each people}}`, you could probably just do `this._id`, but it's hard to tell without seeing the templates.

```
People.update(this._id, { $set: { name: $(e.currentTarget).val()}});
```

I'd also suggest logging these values to the console before the update to make sure the callback is getting executed and that you are reading the right values.

Comment: You need to give me a little more to help you. In what way does it not work? What is the result of `console.log(this._id, $(e.currentTarget).val())` in your event callback?

Comment: Sorry, yes $ helped me! Thank you!